# How can I do a regex match string in a string which contains some characters or not?

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have the following string and want to strip out "two three" whether it is in parenthesis or not.

```
one two three four
one (two three) four
one ( two three ) four
one (two three four
one two three) four
one ( two three four
one two three ) four
```

I want to strip these to

```
one four
```

I tried that but no luck.

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\(| )two(.*?)three( |\))\S+ */i', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex :

```
(\(? ?two three ?\)?)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/pW5wB1/1)

Comment: Thanks, you're the hero of the day!

Answer (score 0):

The point is to match spaces or beginning of string + parenthesis or not + spaces + 'the string to strip' + spaces + parenthesis or not + spaces or end of string.

```
$str = preg_replace('/(^|\s+)\(?\s*the string to strip\s*\)?(\s+|$)/i', ' ', $str);
```

This may result in a space at the begining or the end, but you can trim it later. I think it is the simplest solution.